# SendGrid issues with React Application

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I'm attempting to use sendgrid in my React application to send emails. I keep getting errors: 'can't resolve fs' and can't resolve 'path'. These issues are linked to the node.modules 'node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes'.
I have attempted to remove them. But no luck, anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: Sendgrid is a Node.js library meant to be run on a server. I'm guessing you're attempting to use it in a browser? `fs` and `path` don't exist in the browser. Browsers don't have filesystem (`fs`) access. You need to run SendGrid on a server

Comment: Thanks @CharlieMartin. Any idea how I would set that up? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with back-end..

Comment: Google will help you more than I can here. Search for how to build an express.js application

Answer (score 0):

You are running a backend code on the browser frontend.

Use Server Side rendering with NextJS or use simple NodeJS backend Code to achieve this.